# When I bounced by scroll, I want to change the size of the bound of Image and the size of the bound of the table

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, parallax

When I bounced by scroll, I want to change the size of the bound of Image and the size of the bound of the table.

How can I do it?

I made two images.

I want it this way.

[image]

And it scrolled below.

[image: I want it this way.]

Comment: What did you try, what research did you do? Ask a specific question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, check this out,  [NTParallaxView](https://github.com/demon1105/NTParallaxView) - it helps you create a tableview(scrollview) with parallax effect, much like the top view of Path's timeline, by a easier way.

Comment: Thank you for telling me NTParallaxView!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your ImageView bounds in the following method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

     imgView.frame = CGRectMake(imgView.frame.origin.x, imgView.frame.origin.y, imgView.frame.size.width, height+scrollView.contentOffset.y); // height is static which is the  default height of imgView object.

     imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;//This is to scale your image.

}
```